# Using Jackson XML Mapper, how to serialize more than one properties using same local name

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I have an instance of a class that looks as following

```
public class SomeEntity{
private OpMetric metric = Options.MEASURED;

private Scope scope = Scopes.GLOBAL;
```

}

Which need to be serialized into following XML

```
<SomeEntity xmlns="">       
    <op-metric>
        <value>0.3</value>
    </op-metric>
    <calculated-scope>          
        <value>updated-global</value>
    </calculated-scope>
</SomeEntity >
```

in both cases the value to be set in the xml is **calculated** based on enum values of the original fields ,meaning I need to use getters (+ @JsonIgnore on the fields ) and not just annotate the fields.
I've tried to use the following annotation on the getters to generate the format

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = false, localName = "value")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="op-metric")
```

but it can only be used on one of them due to collision when using the same local name :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "value":
```

Using Mixins did not advance me much since obviously the same limitation applies there  as well.

How should I go about creating this XML structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up creating special methods for the purpose of XML creation ,each of which returns an instance of a class whose only field is named "value", which is then "automatically" gets serialized into the format required .
Annotations were added in using Jackson mixin